# Find Number of lines in a folder

Tags: php

Is it possible using PHP to parse through an entire directory to find number of lines of code in all the files in the dir so this value can be output to the screen - using PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$dit = new DirectoryIterator(".");
$count = 0;
$dit->rewind();
while ($dit->valid()) {
    if ($dit->isFile()) {
        foreach (new SplFileObject($dit->current()) as $line) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    $dit->next();
}
echo $count; //output line count
```

To include subdirectories:

```
$dit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("."));
$count = 0;
$dit->rewind();
while ($dit->valid()) {
    if ($dit->isFile()) {
        foreach (new SplFileObject($dit->current()) as $line) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    $dit->next();
}
echo $count; //output line count
```

Comment: nice this worked perfect! so i am to assume if i put this in a directory which has files in the directory AND folders in the directory that it will count the number of lines of code in the entire directory (files + folders in the parent dir this code sits in)?

Comment: i think this only counts the top level folder

Comment: @Hol It does. I'll edit the answer, if you want the subfolders.

Comment: Great answer, I've never used that object before... learned something new today. :-)

Comment: @Artefacto, the new code seems to be showing the same amount of code as the single dir version.

Comment: ah nm i spoke too soon. takes a while to load :) let me poke around with this TY SO MUCH

Comment: How would you make this show the number of characters instead of the number of lines?

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't be particularly efficient, but you could load each file in the directory and count the number of lines:

```
$total_lines = 0;
chdir($directory);

foreach (glob("*") as $file)
{
  if (is_file($file))
  {
    $total_lines += count(file($file));
  }
}
```

You might want a more restrictive glob construct if the directory contains non-text files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

By compining information from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) and [here](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/php/file-functions/count-lines.php) you get:

```
<?php
  if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    $count = 0;
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $lines = file($file); 
        $count += count($lines);
    }
    closedir($handle);
    echo($count);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHPLOC](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc):

> phploc is a tool for quickly measuring the size and analyzing the structure of a PHP project.

which will give you detailed listing about Lines of Code (Comment and Non-Comment) as well as other metrics, like method distribution, cylcomatic complexity and so on.

Another option would be to use this shell command

```
echo (int) exec('wc -l filename.txt');
```

From the [wc man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wc):

> wc - print the number of newlines, words, and bytes in files
>
> ```
>     -l, --lines
>       print the newline counts
> ```

Programmatically, use [Daniel's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095127/find-number-of-lines-in-a-folder/3095162#3095162) or [Artefacto's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095127/find-number-of-lines-in-a-folder/3095168#3095168).